# no panic while printing/accessing slice indexes which are out of bounds

Tags: go, slice

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    is := []int{1, 2}

    fmt.Println(is[2:]) // no panic here - this includes is[2] which is out of bound still no panic
    fmt.Println(is[3:]) // but panic here
    fmt.Println(is[2]) // panic here which is acceptable
}
```

In above mentioned program, there is no panic for is[2:] even though we are accessing element from is[2] to on wards and the slice is having only 2 elements. Why is it so?

Comment: *"Why is it so?"* Slicing is not indexing. `is[2:]` is not "accessing" `is[2]`.

Comment: @mkopriva Yeah, but then slicing from index 2 should not be allowed as it is not present. let me rephrase it ```is[2:]``` means elements from ```is[2]``` till the end of ```is[]```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [go spec on slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) spells out the requirements for indices used in slicing:

> The indices are in range if 0 <= low <= high <= max <= cap(a), otherwise they are out of range.

As for [index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions), the relevant requirement is:

> the index x is in range if 0 <= x < len(a), otherwise it is out of
>   range

Your slice has `len(a) == cap(a) == 2`. Your three test cases are:

- **slicing**: `low == 2` which is equal to `cap(a)`: **in range**
- **slicing**: `low == 3` which is greater than `cap(a)`: **out of range**
- **indexing**: `x == 2` which is equal to `len(a)`: **out of range**